# format page sizes for 136 pages magazine for printing

Tags: print-design

we produced a magazine with 136 pages and send for printing. But the number of pages is too much for simple binding. In order to make content readable we would need to add some space on the pages format - we think. But is this the solution, or what would we need to do?

Thank you
Stephan

Comment: There's not really enough detail to guess from. What do you call 'simple' binding, saddle-stitch, perfect? 136 pages is only 34 sheets, that's well inside tolerance for saddle stitching, but a bit thin for perfect binding. ..or do you mean 136 sheets? What stock, what size… What does your bindery have to say about it? They'd know what they can handle, far better than we would.

Comment: Read thru and see if this helps -https://www.paperspecs.com/caught-our-eye/perfect-binding-vs-saddle-stitching/

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thank you very much for your prompt answer. It is 136 pages or actually 68 pages printed both sides. We have had a 110 / 55 pages version printed and it was put together with glue (this makes the publication about 1 cm think, which is covered by the extended back cover. Thing is that this is with our partner now and they just got back to me saying content is not readable due to the binding. But ok, I will force them to solve this with their printing house - not sure why they didn't. Again, thanks so much for answering! All the best, Stephan

Comment: If you only supplied the artwork but didn't do the final pagination layout, I'd say there has been a communication error between client & printer. You need different layout for prefect binding compared to stitched. Perfect needs a constant offset on the bound edge, though it will change depending on how many pages make up each full sheet & what order they fold it down in, stitched needs a moving offset, different for every sheet. These are things the print shop must know, & probably will do for the client at a cost, as it's pretty tricky if you're guessing.

Comment: A print provider *should* have handled gutter offsets (creep). If they didn't, they messed up. Creep depends on the stock used, it's thickness along with the number of pages. Since typically the print provider knows the stock.. and is doing prepress, they adjust for creep. Unless the layout has *zero* margins and text runs right the page edge, it's unlikely it's a layout issue.

Comment: I also think this question is a bit unclear. If the problem is that the book cannot open enough for the reader to properly read the text close to the spine, it's because the inner margins aren't wide enough. That's a layout problem imo. What should the print house do about it?